# how to implement my CSS transition to my website

Tags: css, button, sass, css-animations, css-transitions

I have to create button animation like below:
https://media.giphy.com/media/YLgJHbH1u916XSo3JD/giphy.gif

I did it with "transition" but now can't implement that solution to my website.
my button animation solution: http://jsfiddle.net/guhqcxzt/

My website part where I wanna implement it on 'li' tags. (html and scss)

```
 <nav class="left-side">
            <ul class="navigations">

                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>


                <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>


                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>


            </ul>
            <div class="rights">&copy; 2021 All rights reserved.</div>
        </nav>
```

```
nav,
.left-side {
    @include flex(space-between, center, column);
    min-height: 90vh;
    background: $color-grey-dark-1;
    padding: 5rem 0 3rem 0;
    width: 18%;
    color: $color-grey-light-1;
}

.navigations {
    width: 100%;

    li {
        list-style: none;

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $color-grey-light-1;
            display: block;
            padding: 2rem 0;
            margin: 0.5rem 0;
            padding-left: 30%;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
        }
    }
}

a:hover {
    background: $color-primary-light;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

add  transition in `<a>` tag

```
navigations {
    width: 100%;
   li {
    list-style: none;

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $color-grey-light-1;
        display: block;
        padding: 2rem 0;
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
        padding-left: 30%;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        transition:0.5s;
    }
}
}

a:hover {
    background: $color-primary-light;
}
```

Comment: thank, now i got a problem with text inside <a> tag. Transitions work fine but how to stay text center in <li> tag when transition is in progress? here's JSFiddle with liveDemo: https://jsfiddle.net/5wcfxsru/15/

Comment: use ::before and ::after in css for animation

Answer (score 0):

do you want this one?

try this code :

```css
 nav,.left-side
 {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     min-height: 90vh;
     background: black;
     padding: 4rem 0 3rem 0;
     width:300px;
     color: grey;
 }
 .navigations
 {
    width: 100%;
 }
 li 
 {
     position:relative;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: flex-start;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
 }
 li::before
 {
     content:'';
     position:absolute;
     width:0%;
     height:70px;
     background:red;
     left:-20px;
     transition:0.5s;
}
li:hover::before
{
      width:100%;
} 
a
{
     position:relative;
     color: grey;
      margin: 0.5rem 0;
      width:92.4%;
      text-decoration:none;
  }
.rights {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="left-side">
       <ul class="navigations">
             <li ><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
             <li><a href="#"> HOTE </a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
     <div class="rights">&copy; 2021 All rights reserved.</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This code works halfway because its just slide from left to right :) Any idea to do all the way like this? : https://media.giphy.com/media/YLgJHbH1u916XSo3JD/giphy.gif

Comment: For him use java script event